# Simple Flyway example fails with ORA-00911 invalid character

Tags: oracle, flyway

I'm trying out Flyway with a simple example, and somehow fell into an error I don't understand. This is just a "hello world" type project.

This migration script fails as posted here, but succeeds if I either remove the ";" at the end, or change the column default to anything but 'N'. Lowercase 'n' also fails.

I've used a hex editor to confirm everything is ascii, and can successfully run the migration script in Toad and SQuirreL. It only fails when going through Flyway.

I've also used the debugger to capture the SQL string within Flyway before it gets executed, and it looks fine there as well. Copying it from the debugger to Toad or SQuirreL also succeeds.

It's got to be something simple that I'm missing, but I can't see what it is. Any ideas?

Here's my only migration script:

```
CREATE TABLE APP_USER
(
  USER_ID        INTEGER NOT NULL,
  USER_CONFIRMED CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N'
);
```

and the code:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;
import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway;

public class FlywayTask {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FlywayTask flywayTask = new FlywayTask();
        try {
            flywayTask.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {

        System.out.println("FlywayTask Running!");

        // Create Flyway instance w/ a datasource
        Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
        flyway.setDataSource(buildDS());

        // Delete the WHOLE SCHEMA!! DANGER!!
        flyway.clean();

        // Start the migration
        flyway.migrate();
    }

    public DataSource buildDS() {
        ...
        return ods;
    }
}
```

Running this against Oracle 10g or 11g results in this error:

```
FlywayTask Running!
Jun 12, 2015 10:38:40 AM org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.VersionPrinter printVersion
INFO: Flyway 3.2 by Boxfuse
Jun 12, 2015 10:38:41 AM org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory createDbSupport
INFO: Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=scan-dev-db.dev.probuild.com )(PORT=1525))    (CONNECT_DATA =        (SERVER = DEDICATED)        (SERVICE_NAME=NTRADEV.dev.probuild.com))) (Oracle 11.2)
Jun 12, 2015 10:38:42 AM org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean cleanSchema
INFO: Cleaned schema "TOM1" (execution time 00:00.686s)
Jun 12, 2015 10:38:42 AM org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate validate
INFO: Validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.016s)
Jun 12, 2015 10:38:42 AM org.flywaydb.core.internal.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl createIfNotExists
INFO: Creating Metadata table: "TOM1"."schema_version"
Jun 12, 2015 10:38:43 AM org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate migrate
INFO: Current version of schema "TOM1": << Empty Schema >>
Jun 12, 2015 10:38:43 AM org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate applyMigration
INFO: Migrating schema "TOM1" to version 1 - Tables
Jun 12, 2015 10:38:43 AM org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate applyMigration
SEVERE: Migration of schema "TOM1" to version 1 failed! Please restore backups and roll back database and code!
org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.FlywaySqlScriptException: 
Migration V1__Tables.sql failed
-------------------------------
SQL State  : 22019
Error Code : 911
Message    : ORA-00911: invalid character
Location   : db/migration/V1__Tables.sql (C:\Workspaces\luna_64\flyway-spike\target\classes\db\migration\V1__Tables.sql)
Line       : 3
Statement  : CREATE TABLE APP_USER
(
  USER_ID        INTEGER NOT NULL,
  USER_CONFIRMED CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N'
);

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript.execute(SqlScript.java:117)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationExecutor.execute(SqlMigrationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$5.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:284)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$5.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:282)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:72)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.applyMigration(DbMigrate.java:282)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.access$800(DbMigrate.java:46)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:207)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:156)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:72)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:156)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1059)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1006)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1418)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1006)
    at com.probuild.spike.flyway.FlywayTask.run(FlywayTask.java:34)
    at com.probuild.spike.flyway.FlywayTask.main(FlywayTask.java:16)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:999)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1315)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1890)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1855)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:304)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate.executeStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:238)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript.execute(SqlScript.java:114)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: Scary stuff.  My favorite lines are: "Delete the WHOLE SCHEMA!! DANGER!!" followed by: "Please restore backups and roll back database and code!"

Comment: Well it is just a hello world, mostly copied from flyway's website.

Comment: I may have solved this. Changing the line to:

    USER_CONFIRMED CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 'N'

seems to resolve it. I tried this after seeing how SqlDeveloper exported existing tables.

Answer (score 1):

It is know bug of Flyway. It is fixed already, but it will be released in Flyway 4.0. Take a look at [issue 1080](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1080)

Comment: I'd love to mark this as an answer, but am beginning to wonder if it is/was an Oracle bug. 

The same code works now, with Flyway v3.2.1. I can't even get it to fail. The only change I know of is that the databases themselves have been through a patch cycle. Everything else is unchanged.

I'll keep trying to replicate the problem to see if something about issue 1080 is involved here.

Comment: It is Flyway bug. If there was some keyword in value or name, Flyway parse it by this. Let's say you want to insert these data : `INSERT INTO movies (movie_name) VALUES ('From Dusk Till Dawn')` but Flyway understand it like Select query, because of 'From'.  BTW flyway 4.0 is out and working fine. Also some nice features like rollback if script fail ... check it out.